# Setting TEXINPUTS in El Capitan (OS X)

Tags: mac, texinputs

I updated to El Capitan some time ago. My TeX installation works fine, but there is a problem: When I run latex from inside TeXShop, it does not see the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable. **When I run `pdflatex` from the Terminal, everything works correctly.** (So this is not about changed paths to the executables, access to `/usr/bin` or `/Library`, etc.)

The root of the problem is that on OS X, applications launched from the GUI (Launchpad) do not inherit from any shell that reads my startup files. Prior to the upgrade, I could set `TEXINPUTS` with the command `launchctl setenv TEXINPUTS path:path:more-path::`. But this has stopped working: `launchctl` tells me it set the variable, but it does not get passed to child processes. Does anyone know how we're supposed to do this on El Capitan?

Comment: There is no need to set TEXINPUTS if you installed TeX Live via MacTeX. Your personal tree will start at ~/Library/texmf.

Comment: Let me add that you can add symbolic links to ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex of directories which contain your personal files.

Comment: Symlinking `~/Library/texmf` to the true location (there's more than `latex` files in `TEXINPUTS`!) sounds like a tolerable work-around, thanks. But what if I have multiple locations on `TEXINPUTS`? (Fortunately I don't on this computer.)

Comment: Symlink each folder into ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex.

Comment: Not everything in `texmf` is a latex style.

Comment: First... creat texmf/tex/latex in ~/Library if it doesn't already exist. Then create symlinks of all folders with packages, etc. in that folder. Next, what other stuff do you have that TEXINPUTS would find?