# How to properly define TEXINPUTS

Tags: input, environment-variables, texinputs

There are numerous questions on this site (and elsewhere on the web) how to define $TEXINPUTS and other strategies for including non-standard locations to be searched by TeX.
See, for instance the discussions
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable),
[here (for texmaker)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411418/texinputs-and-texmaker-latexila),
[here (for Texstudio)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223284/setting-texinputs-in-texstudio-mac-os-x),
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12363/local-texmf-tree-vs-texinputs?rq=1),
[here (for MikTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696668/texinputs-texmf-and-other-variables),
[here (for TeXShop)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336101/setting-texinputs-in-el-capitan-os-x),
[here (macOS)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550256/setting-up-texinputs-on-macos-catalina), or
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306790/find-files-in-subdirectories-to-use-with-input).
From all those discussions (a lot of helpful explanations buried in comments) I gather that there are many different ways of defining the variable and that it depends on the operating system, TeX distribution, and program what will work and what won't.

I'm on macOS and use TeXShop. I have a location at `~/custompath/input/` with a bunch of subfolders for `graphics`, `figures` etc., which I would like TeX to access without having to specify explicit paths (which I know I can do via `\def\input@path{...}`).

Temporarily, I've learned I can define the variable via command line with

```
export TEXINPUTS=.:~/custompath/input//:
```

A more permanent solution should be to add `TEXINPUTS = .:~/custompath/input//:` either to

```
~/.bashrc
```

or

```
 /usr/local/texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf
```

The first method (via `export TEXINPUTS=.:~/custompath/input//:`) does work as expected when I run `pdflatex` from the same command line window. I understand that since it's temporary I can't expect this to work in TeXShop.

But I fail at getting any of the other methods to work.
Placing the magic line in `~/.bashrc` has no effect whatsoever.

When I add it to `texmf.cnf`, then I can run from the command line

```
kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'
```

and that does return  `.:~/custompath/input//:`
However, compiling (again from the command line `pdflatex ~/custompath/testing.tex`) gives me:

```
`! LaTeX Error: File `testinput.tex' not found.`
```

And, needless to say, nothing works from TeXShop.

Is there a bulletproof way to define an additional location to be searched by TeX that will always work, no matter if I'm invoking LaTeX from the command line, using TeXShop, or another front end? My hunch is the answer is no, but perhaps someone can explain how to get it to work for different systems/installations/front ends. (I'm particularly interested in TeXShop, of course, but it seems people on other platforms frequently run into similar issues, so maybe it's worth to have an authoritative answer for all scenarios ...).

MWE for what it's worth, with `testinput.tex` at `~/custompath/input/figures/project1/` :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} test document \par
\input{testinput.tex}
%\input{~/custompath/input/figures/project1/testinput.tex} % 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would expect `~/texmf`  is already in your default path so the simplest thing is to use that name rather than `~tex`. Check `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'`

Comment: don't use the environment variable TEXINPUTS as that masks the setting in texmf.cnf and your editor, if launched from the dektop may not share the same environment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The point of my question was to find a way to input a random custom folder that is not already in the default path. I've edited the question to make that clearer, calling the folder in my homefolder now "custompath" as opposed to "tex" to not create any confusion.  In regards to your second comment, if not `$TEXINPUTS`, then how can I achieve what I want  (making a custom folder plus subfolders visible to tex)?  Is there an alternative method?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `~/texmf`? It's possible to add an addition tree either permanently (as I do for `/usr/share/...`) or temporarily as people sometimes do for testing. But there are particular reasons for those structures and it isn't clear whether you plan to structure this as another tree anyway.

Comment: @cfr Well, in my particular use case I have all my writing projects in one place, logically organized in an old-school folder structure with subfolders for different projects under the system Documents folder (the actual path is quite long, simplified in the example above).  All research material for these projects is organized there as well, so I wouldn't want the entire directory to be available to TeX – only one folder (called `input`) with subfolders with files that are shared between projects (figures, examples, graphs, tables, pictures, etc.).

Comment: @jan I use a mixture of 2 approaches for that kind of case. (1) In some cases, I put the resources under `$TEXMFHOME`. (2) In other cases, I keep them outside, especially if they are relevant to only a certain category of documents (e.g. they're chunks or examples I use in teaching materials, but not writing or research). Especially for teaching, I add some of these directories in custom classes or packages and only quite specific ones in each project or document config. All custom classes and packages are under `$TEXHOME`. These also define commands which utilise other, task-specific places.

Comment: macOS GUI programs do not read `.bashrc` or similar: this is a design decision by Apple  - as such you cannot use exactly the same methods for all OSs.

Comment: you can symlink your tex folders under texmf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sure, that's the workaround I've been using – but I was hoping there was a better/official solution

Comment: set the variables in texmf.cnf (not the environment) is the other way,

Comment: @JosephWright ok, understood ... but even when I add `TEXINPUTS=.:~/custompath/input//:` to `texmf.cnf`, while `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'` returns the custom location, when compiling I still get the file not found error (whether in a GUI program or from the command line).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Could you explain how?  I thought that was I was doing (which didn't work) ...

Comment: make sure it's not set in the shell. `TEXINPUTS=.:~/custompath/input//: to texmf.cnf`  sounds wrong, that will mask the original setting, probably something like `TEXINPUTS.tex           = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/tex/{plain,generic,latex,}//`    you want to set TEXMFHOME as described in the comments in texmf.cnf `% Per-user texmf tree(s) -- organized per the TDS, as usual.  To define
% more than one per-user tree, set this to a list of directories in
% braces, as described above.  (This used to be HOMETEXMF.)  ~ expands
% to %USERPROFILE% on Windows, $HOME otherwise.
TEXMFHOME = ~/texmf`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   I'm making some progress figuring this out. Adding `TEXMFHOME = ~/custompath/input//`  to  `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf.cnf` does work but only if I move the file in question to a subfolder of `~/custompath/input/tex/latex/`  –   "organized per the TDS, as usual" (I get it now). 
But what I was trying to accomplish is to directly input the folder without yet again having to bury the files two levels down (as then my current method with a symlink is still easier). From what I had been reading, it seemed that TEXINPUTS was the way to go but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: you could set TEXINPUTS directly to whatever directory you want but make sure to add it to a copy of the default setting or you will end up with only allowing your new directory and removing the main texlive tree from the input path.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, but can you explain what you mean by "add it to a copy of the default setting"?

Comment: looking in my texmf.cnf I see `TEXINPUTS.pdflatex      = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/tex/{latex,generic,}//`  so you want `TEXINPUTS.pdflatex      = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/tex/{latex,generic,}//,/some.path.to/somewhere` if you just set it to your path pdflatex won't look in the standard places so `\documentclass{article}` wouldn't find `article.cls`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added `TEXINPUTS.pdflatex = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/tex/{latex,generic,}//,/~/custompath/input` to `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf.cnf` – but still getting file not found :(

Comment: (as specified above, file is at `~/custompath/input/figures/project1/testinput.tex`)

Comment: semicolon not comma and not /~  just ~ or use the full path

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I still get "file not found"

Comment: sorry I have no mac. I'm out. Stick to symlinks?